# jQuery widget factory _destroy method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-widget-factory

I am trying to create a timer widget that can be initialized with a number of seconds and then  reset at any time by making a new call with a new 'number of seconds' to countdown from. So far I have this which creates the timer fine and counts down.

What I am trying to do is call the _destroy method first inside the _create method to remove the timer that is already on the element and also use window.clearInterval to stop the timer being re-added. this.interval is set in the _start method and then referenced in the _destroy method but I think the problem lies with the scope of this.interval.

This is what I have so far, but my _destroy method does not seem to be clearing the interval and I can't figure out why.

```
$.widget('time.countdown', {

    options : {
        remaining : (2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
        updatefreq: 1000
    },

    _create : function () {
        'use strict';
        this._destroy();
    },

    _start: function () {
        'use strict';
        var secs = this.options.remaining;

        this.interval = window.setInterval((function (elem, secs) {

            return function () {

                secs -= 1;

                var days     = Math.floor(secs / (24 * 60 * 60)),
                    div_hr   = secs % (24 * 60 * 60),
                    hours    = Math.floor(div_hr / (60 * 60)),
                    div_min  = secs % (60 * 60),
                    minutes  = Math.floor(div_min / 60),
                    div_secs = div_min % 60,
                    seconds  = Math.ceil(div_secs),
                    time_parts = {
                        "d": days,
                        "h": hours,
                        "m": minutes,
                        "s": seconds
                    },
                    tstring = '',
                    c;

                for (c in time_parts) {
                    if (time_parts.hasOwnProperty(c)) {
                        tstring += time_parts[c] + c + ' ';
                    }
                }

                elem.html(tstring);
            };

        }(this.element, secs)), this.options.updatefreq);
    },

    _destroy: function() {
        'use strict';
        if (this.interval !== undefined) {
            window.clearInterval(this.interval);
        }
        this.element.html('');
    }

});
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something strange with your code is that there is no call to the "private" `_start()` function, but nvm.

You should add a public `reset()` function to :

- set the new `remaining` value,
- clearInterval,
- then call the `_start()` function

You should then call this `reset()` function when needed. Have a look in this code and explanations below :

```
(function($) {

    $.widget('time.countdown', {

        options : {
            remaining : (2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
            updatefreq: 1000
        },

        _create : function () {
            'use strict';
            this._start();
        },

        _setOption: function(key, value) {
            key == 'remaining' ?
                this.reset(value) :
                this._super(key, value);
        },

        _start: function () {
            'use strict';
            // your countdown code
        },

        reset: function(remaining) {
            // You should perform some checks on the given value
            this.options.remaining = remaining;
            this._destroy();
            this._start();
        },

        _destroy: function() {
            'use strict';
            if (this.interval !== undefined)
                window.clearInterval(this.interval);
            this.element.html('');
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Note that the `_create()` function is called only once, at creation time. So if you apply the plugin many times on the same element with no args like `$('#timer').countdown();` then the `_start()` will be called only once (on first call).

You can now reset the countdown with a new value in differents ways :

```
// new value to set = 3600

// Call to the "public" `reset()` function
$('#timer').countdown('reset', 3600);

// Call to the `_setOption()`
$('#timer').countdown({remaining: 3600});

// Call to the `_setOption()` 
$('#timer').countdown('option', 'remaining', 3600);
```

Comment: Hi, I did have a call to the _start() method in the _create method but I accidentally took it out with some checks on the options to make the code clearer for the question.

Comment: Your example makes it a lot clearer. I'm still quite new with jQ widgets but this really helps. I eventually fixed it by making a call to the public destroy method before re-initializing the widget on the element. I will be refactoring it after seeing your example. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it helped. I agree it is not so obvious to start working with the widget factory, there is a bit of learning but I believe the benefits justified the work :)